# Display issues with RasberryPi3 php var_dump in browser

Tags: php, browser, raspberry-pi3, chromium, var-dump

I have recently setup my raspberry pi 3 with PHP and Apache2. All works okay, i can run scripts no problem.

I have always used a browser (chrome in w10) to debug. But when i use chromium or firefox in the Raspberrypi3 arrays always display as one long string, this is when using var_dump. Makes debugging a pain in the ...

Any way of making array elements display on separate lines in a browser in raspberrypi, like they do in chrome on W10 with var_dump?

Kind Regards

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you see different results using `var_dump()` with different browsers, but you can use this to dump the content of a variable in a readable way.

```php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arg);
die();
```

You could take it a step further and implement a simple function:

```php
function dumper(): void
{
    $args = func_get_args();

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
       print_r($arg);
    }

    die();
}
```

As an example:

```php
<?php

function dumper(): void
{
    $args = func_get_args();

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
       print_r($arg);
    }

    die();
}

$myArray = [1, 'a', new stdClass(), 'foo' => ['bar', 'baz']];

dumper($myArray);
```

Which will produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => a
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [foo] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
            [1] => baz
        )

)
```

Hope this can help you! I suggest you to look into xDebug or Ray (by Spatie) to better debug your scripts

Comment: Thank you for your response, i was really hoping not to have to edit the code. I have many thousands of lines to go through. Kind of hoping there was an easy fix with raspberry browser, but i guess not.